# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null in Chrome

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Got this exception in Chrome Browser:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null\".

Working fine in IE Browser, only issue in Chrome.

below is the javascript code that will display the data...

```
<head runat="server">
<title>Crossbrowser Test Page</title>

<script language ="javascript" type="text/javascript" for="window" event="onload">      
        document.getElementById('divAccount').style.display  = "block"   
        document.getElementById('divSecurity').style.display  = "block"   
</script>

</head>
<body>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="divAccount" style="display:none">
        <table border="1" style="background-color:Red; height:75px; width:500px"  >
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Column1
                </td>
                <td>
                    Column2
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="divSecurity" style="display:none">
        <table border="1" style="background-color:Gray; height:75px; width:500px"  >
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Column3
                </td>
                <td>
                    Column4
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
```

Thanks,
Uday

Comment: Can you display the html code?

Comment: please add HTML

Comment: added the html full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your  block to the bottom of your code. After your body content.

Because the browser is attempting to run the JS before the DOM are defined.